# Python snippet showing weird behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the code for reference:-

```
temp = [0 for _ in range(5)]
dp = [temp for _ in range(len(wt)+1)]
        
for i in range(len(wt)):
    for j in range(len(dp[0])):
        print("outside inner loop if statement:",dp,i,j)
        if j-wt[i] >=0:
            print(i,j)
            dp[i][j] = "y"
            print("inside inner loop if statement dp:", dp)
```

Here's the relevant output:-

```
outside inner loop if statement: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] 0 0

outside inner loop if statement: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] 0 1

outside inner loop if statement: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] 0 2

outside inner loop if statement: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] 0 3

outside inner loop if statement: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] 0 4

0 4

inside inner loop if statement dp: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 'y'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 'y'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 'y'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 'y']]
```

The moment the flow goes in the if block when i=0 and j=4, every fourth column changes to 'y' even though the ideal behavior should be dp[0][4] = 'y'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're only iterating through `dp[0]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `temp` is stored in `dp` multiple times you are changing all occurrences of `temp` when you do `dp[0][4] = 'y'` so it changes all rows to have 'y'.

Instead you need:

```
dp = [[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(len(wt)+1)]
        
for i in range(len(wt)):
    for j in range(len(dp[0])):
        print("outside inner loop if statement:",dp,i,j)
        if j-wt[i] >=0:
            print(i,j)
            dp[i][j] = "y"
            print("inside inner loop if statement dp:", dp)
```

Because `dp = [[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(len(wt)+1)]` will re evaluate `[0 for _ in range(5)]` each time as a different list.

Comment: Thanks, I can not upvote but I didn't know about this at all.

Comment: @DrDoggo you can select the answer if you think it helped!